# ASP Submit Button onclick/_doPostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, form-submit

**The form begins:**

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "recordssbook", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SubmitForm" }))
    { %>
```

**The submit button I would like to validate (there are other submit buttons in the same form):**

```
<div><input type="submit" value="Delete Selected"  id ="DeleteButton" name="DeleteButton" onclick="deleteRecordsDialog();"/></div>
```

**The buttons in my confirm dialog in js that automatically returns false:**

```
function deleteRecordsDialog() {
    var returnThis;
    var numRecords = selectedRecordsArr.length;
    document.getElementById("popupContainer");
    var html = ""
    html= html + '<table>';
    html= html + '<tr>';
    html= html + '<td class="warning-icon-cell"></td>';
    html= html + '<td style="padding-left: 5px;">';
    if (numAddresses == 1) {
        html = html + '<p>You have chosen to delete a record.</p>';
    }
    else {
        html = html + '<p>You have chosen to delete ' + numRecords + ' records.</p>';
    }
    html= html + '<p>Are you sure you wish to proceed?</p>';
    html= html + '</td>';
    html= html + '</tr>';
    html = html + '</table>';
    if (numAddresses == 1) {
        html = html + '<div><input type="button" value="Yes, Delete Contact" style="width: 160px; onclick="document.DSubmitForm.HDeleteButton.submit(); CloseDialog();"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="CloseDialog();"/></div>';
    }
    else {
        html = html + '<div><input type="submit" value="Yes, Delete Contact(s)" style="width: 160px; onclick="document.DSubmitForm.HDeleteButton.submit(); CloseDialog();"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="CloseDialog();"/></div>';
    }
    html = html + '</div>';
    html = html + '</div>';
    html = html + '</div>';
    html = html + '</div>';
    OpenDialog(html, 350, 180, false, "Delete Contact")
    return false;
}
```

My issues:

1. Even with onclick returning false the form is submitted:
   I can change the input type to button instead of submit, and this should work if I can get the psuedo submit to work
2. is _doPostBack another way to submit the form?: From my google searches I think this should simulate the submit but when I make the submit button a regular button as stated in number 1 clicking "Yes, Delete Record(s)" doesn't submit the form.
3. I have multiple submit buttons which makes this more complex
4. I cannot use JQuery's easy .dialog

If someone can help me out in getting this to work I would GREATLY appreciate it!

Thanks!!

**EDIT**
So the html a list of records with buttons that can query based on letter, add a record, delete a record and edit a record. All of these buttons are submit buttons in the same form.

```
<td><input type="submit" value="ABC"  name="SubmitButton"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="DEF"  name="SubmitButton" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="GHI"  name="SubmitButton" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="JKL"  name="SubmitButton"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="MNO"  name="SubmitButton"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="PQRS"  name="SubmitButton" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="TUV"  name="SubmitButton"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="WXYZ" name="SubmitButton" /></td>
<div><input type="button" value="Add Contact" id="addAddress" onclick="AddAddresDialog()" /></div>
<div><input type="button" value="View &amp; Edit Selected" id="EditButton" name="EditButton"  onclick="updateAddressDialog()"/></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Delete Selected"  id ="DeleteButton" name="SubmitButton" /></div>
```

I only want to add the confirm dialog to the delete button being clicked. I want to confirm it using a custom dialog window which is a div on the site master that appears as a pop up by being placed on top of a mask that covers the whole screen which is created in deleteRecordsDialog().

What I want to do is change the submit button for the delete task (id="DeleteButton) to a regular button that just opens the dialog created by deleteRecordsDialog() instead of the form submission it does now. The "Yes, Delete Contact(s)" button in the custom confirm dialog should take on that task of submitting the form with the value "Delete Selected" just as the submit button does now.

Comment: I added the whole script. Let me know if anything else is needed. I am using MVC3 asp.net. The ASP-classic must have been an autocorrect from stackoverflow, sorry! Essentially I need to submit the form on the records page from a custom pop up dialog formed in a div on the site.master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to really understand what you are trying to do without your html. However, you can try out the following:

**HTML**:

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Selected"  id ="DeleteButton" name="DeleteButton" onclick="deleteRecordsDialog();"/>
    <input type="button"  id ="DeleteButtonSubmit" name="DeleteButtonSubmit" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

**Javscript**:

To create button for modal:

```
 html = html + '<div><input type="button" value="Yes, Delete Contact(s)" style="width: 160px; onclick="deleteContact();"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="CloseDialog();"/></div>';
```

Function to post the delete confirmation:

```
function deleteContact()
{
    document.getElementById('DeleteButtonSubmit').click();
}
```

This function will click a hidden button below the button the user initially clicked. if you setup this button correctly, the form should submit with all of the information you need.

Comment: If I do that I can't get it to submit the form and actually delete the record. If I do change it to a button my custom dialog does pop up, the issue is that I cannot get my "yes" button to simulate the form submission with the Delete Selected parameter.

Comment: But the button in the modal is going to submit the form isnt it? That is what your code seems to indicate.

Comment: But it needs to submit the form with the attribute Delete Selected so the C# knows how to process.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "attribute delete selected". I think we need more information about your form, but I have taken another crack at what you are trying to do if you want to take another look.

Comment: the submit button with value "Delete Selected" triggers the form submit with the value "Delete Selected". The C# code catches this value and runs the code to delete it on the back end. This is done because there are other submit buttons like add/filter a-c/filter c-f etc. what other information would you need to see? I'll try this and get back to you

Comment: I edited my post with, hopefully, a better description of what I'm trying to do. thank you for all of your helpo

Comment: I assume you have tested my last edit and it did not help? Did you update the hidden button to contain the proper information needed to post your form?

Comment: I made a small edit, but I got this to work. Thank you very much!